# Infinite list with notification is hitting scroll function multiple times

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch infinite list of firestore documents when search field has text of minimum 3. Now whenever I am at the bottom of my list, `requestNextPage()` is hitting multiple times. I want it to hit only once.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
        onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {
          if (scrollInfo.metrics.maxScrollExtent == scrollInfo.metrics.pixels &&
              _searchController.text.length >= 3 ) {
            requestNextPage();
          }
          return true;
        },
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: _searchController,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    searchText = value;
                    if (searchText.trim().length >= 3) {
                      requestNextPage();
                    }
                  });
                },
                
              ),
              // Fetch School list from Firebase and display it here
              StreamBuilder<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(
                stream: _streamController.stream,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (_searchController.text.length <= 2) {
                    return const Center();
                  }
                  if (snapshot.data == null) {
                    return Center(
                        child: LoadingWidget(height: 100, width: 100));
                  } else if (snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
                    return NoSchoolFroundWidget(
                      searchText: _searchController.text,
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            SchoolModel school = SchoolModel.fromMap(
                                snapshot.data![index].data()
                                    as Map<String, dynamic>);

                            return SchoolListItem(
                                context, school, widget.onboardingUser);
                          },
                        ),
                        // const SizedBox(height: 20),
                        // Text(
                        //   "Maximum $searchCount results shown\nNo school found? mail us at help@odekh.com",
                        //   textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        //   style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                        // ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void requestNextPage() async {
    //checking if stream is closed
    if (_streamController.isClosed) return;

    //checking if already loading or no more data
    if (!_isRequesting && !_isFinish) {
      QuerySnapshot querySnapshot;
      _isRequesting = true;
      if (_schools.isEmpty) {
        querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('schools')
            .where('isSchool',
                isEqualTo: widget.onboardingUser.courseType ==
                        CourseTypeConstants.inSchool
                    ? true
                    : false)
            .where('searchList',
                arrayContains: _searchController.text.toLowerCase().trim())
            .orderBy('updatedAt', descending: true)
            .limit(searchCount)
            .get();
        log.d("List of schools fetched: querySnapshot: ${querySnapshot.docs}");
      } else {
        //get document from the last of the list
        querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('schools')
            .where('isSchool',
                isEqualTo: widget.onboardingUser.courseType ==
                        CourseTypeConstants.inSchool
                    ? true
                    : false)
            .where('searchList',
                arrayContains: _searchController.text.toLowerCase().trim())
            .orderBy('updatedAt', descending: true)
            .startAfterDocument(_schools[_schools.length - 1])
            .limit(searchCount)
            .get();
      }

      if (querySnapshot != null) {
        int oldSize = _schools.length;
        _schools.addAll(querySnapshot.docs);
        int newSize = _schools.length;
        if (oldSize != newSize) {
          //Added if new posts have new users and adding new users to userMap
          for (var element in querySnapshot.docs) {
            SchoolModel school =
                SchoolModel.fromMap(element.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
          }

          _streamController.add(_schools);
        } else if (newSize == 0) {
          _streamController.add(_schools);
        } else {
          _isFinish = true;
        }
      }
      _isRequesting = false;
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _streamController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: try `requestNextPage` with microTask